# We spun new Jira in K8S with postgres HA and it fails with this error

Tags: postgresql, jira

We spun new Jira in EKS by using the helm chart with postgres HA and it fails with this error:
plugins failed to load during Jira startup.

```
    'com.atlassian.jira.plugins.jira-development-integration-plugin' - 'Atlassian Jira - Plugins - Development Integration Plugin'  failed to load.
        Error creating bean with name 'dataProviderCleanupJob': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.atlassian.jira.exception.DataAccessException: org.ofbiz.core.entity.GenericDataSourceException: Generic Entity Exception occurred in deleteByAnd (SQL Exception while executing the following:DELETE FROM public.clusteredjob WHERE JOB_ID=? (ERROR: cannot execute DELETE in a read-only transaction))
            org.ofbiz.core.entity.GenericDataSourceException: Generic Entity Exception occurred in deleteByAnd (SQL Exception while executing the following:DELETE FROM public.clusteredjob WHERE JOB_ID=? (ERROR: cannot execute DELETE in a read-only transaction))
                Generic Entity Exception occurred in deleteByAnd (SQL Exception while executing the following:DELETE FROM public.clusteredjob WHERE JOB_ID=? (ERROR: cannot execute DELETE in a read-only transaction))
                    SQL Exception while executing the following:DELETE FROM public.clusteredjob WHERE JOB_ID=? (ERROR: cannot execute DELETE in a read-only transaction)
                        ERROR: cannot execute DELETE in a read-only transaction

        It was loaded from /var/atlassian/application-data/jira/plugins/installed-plugins/jira-development-integration-plugin-5.10.3.jar

    'com.pyxis.greenhopper.jira' - 'Jira Agile'  failed to load.
        Error creating bean with name 'greenhopper-launcher': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.opensymphony.module.propertyset.PropertyImplementationException: Failed operation: SetOperation[entityName=GreenHopper.Run.History,entityId=1,propertyKey=lastRunVersion,newType=6,newMapper=TypeMapper[handler=StringPropertyHandler,valueEntity=OSPropertyText]]
            Failed operation: SetOperation[entityName=GreenHopper.Run.History,entityId=1,propertyKey=lastRunVersion,newType=6,newMapper=TypeMapper[handler=StringPropertyHandler,valueEntity=OSPropertyText]]
                Caught PSQLException for select O_S_PROPERTY_ENTRY.id, O_S_PROPERTY_ENTRY.propertytype
from public.propertyentry O_S_PROPERTY_ENTRY
where O_S_PROPERTY_ENTRY.entity_name = ? and O_S_PROPERTY_ENTRY.entity_id = ? and O_S_PROPERTY_ENTRY.property_key = ?
order by O_S_PROPERTY_ENTRY.id desc
for update
                    ERROR: cannot execute SELECT FOR UPDATE in a read-only transaction

        It was loaded from /var/atlassian/application-data/jira/plugins/installed-plugins/jira-greenhopper-plugin-8.20.10.jar
```

Comment: "read-only transaction", something told the database to start a read only transaction. Check your logfiles

Comment: the problem is solved we had HA postgres in k8s cluster and Jira was connecting to the read only pg node